# How to delete a dropbox file?

Tags: java, dropbox

How can I delete a dropbox file?

The only way I found was

```
Metadata metadata = client.files().delete(path);
```

But this is a deprecated version so I need the current one

Comment: think u need to check the documentation of dropbox java api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the current version of the Dropbox Java SDK, for Dropbox API v2, here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java

To delete a file, you should use the `deleteV2` method:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#deleteV2-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-